# Is it safe to keep PS_ON grounded?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I want to disable the 'soft power off' feature of an ATX power supply. So I think of connecting PS_ON and GND with a tweezer and keep it. But when the motherboard wants to shut down and sends high level signal to PS_ON, will the current be too large and damage something?

Comment: If you don't know the type of output driver on the motherboard pin that drives the PS_ON, then you don't know if it is safe to short it externally to ground. Sorry, there is no general answer.

Comment: @winny But there can be issues. The ATX power supply specification says the motherboard can either set output high or let it float. It will be an issue if motherboard pushes high.

Comment: @Justme Gosh darn it. I’ve never encountered such a motherboard but your comment is very valid. Resistor to ground it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AT specification says that the #PS_ON signal should be pulled up inside the power supply to the 5V standby power rail. So it's only necessary for the motherboard to have an open drain or open collector output driving the signal, and that's what most motherboards tend to use.

However, without being certain that your particular motherboard does that, you can't be sure that it won't be damaged if you short the line to GND and it tries to force it high instead of passively allowing it to pulled high. If you get hold of the schematic or you can trace the circuit driving that pin you may be able to determine the type of output used but if not, disconnect the signal by cutting the wire or removing the pin from the connector with a removal tool and tape it up.